# SharePoint 2010 Foundation and Word 2003 Interop

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a workflow that upon approval (only for word .doc) will enable Track Changes and convert a copy of the file to a pdf format.
I'm stuck at opening the file,

[image]

How can I overcome this problem, Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ouch! Using Word Interop server side is one of the worst (if not the worst) mistakes you can do. It is not scalable at all. I've seen so many cases where these kind of interop applications/integrations have taken down the servers. Whatever you're trying to achieve - please stop using Word Interop server side.

What you need to do is to look at Open Office XML SDK (Bing it or Google it). That SDK is a perfectly safe way to work with Office documents (but only the new format; docx, xlsx etc)

Comment: Thats what I've been hearing from the web while googling this issue, Thanks for making it crystal clear, now I can show this to my project manager.